# How to debug a .xml extension as html in chrome?

Tags: html, xml, google-chrome

I am using a library that automatically creates a `sitemap.xml`.

However when I go to `/sitemap.xml` I get an error on chrome:

```
This page contains the following errors:

error on line 4 at column 16: AttValue: " or ' expected
Below is a rendering of the page up to the first error.
```

The error on firefox is:

```
XML Parsing Error: not well-formed
Location: http://example.dev/sitemap.xml
Line Number 4, Column 16:   <meta charset=utf-8 />
----------------------^
```

Yet when I inspect the response it has the normal site template `html` in it with an error:

```
<h2>Error 500</h2>

<div class="error">
Undefined index: lastmod</div></div><!-- content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The `preview` shows the xml error.

So how can I get chrome to display the html version, as it contains a stack trace and other good stuff to debug?

Comment: It'd be easier to just view source, copy everything, paste it into a new .html file and open that. You're not really trying to debug XML (or HTML for that matter).